# Web3: Wait all async calls within a loop are completed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ethereum, web3js

I am using Web3 to get a list of smart contract and then iterate (loop) through each of them to get multiple variables of the smart contracts. Unfortunately, I am not able to execute a function once all the async calls within my loop are done.

Logic:

1. Get the number of Games
2. For i = 0 until i < Games

   - Get the smart contract address (from Smart Contract)
   - Get the Start Time value (from Smart Contract)
   - Get the End Time value (from Smart Contract)
3. (Once all calls of the loop are done)
4. Order the Games by Start Time
5. Display the Games

When I do console.log(contractInstanceGame) (step 3) after my loop, the array is empty as the previous calls are not completed.

Code:

```
var contractInstanceGame = [];

contractAddressRegistry = '0xc0b55bff524b953a5248ccb5a60b00647052ae8b';

// Fetch all the contract addresses
let contractRegistry = web3.eth.contract(contractAbiRegistry);
let contractInstanceRegistry = contractRegistry.at(contractAddressRegistry);

contractInstanceRegistry.numberOfGames(function(err, res) {
  if (!err) {
    let numberOfGames = res.toNumber();
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++) {
      let contractGame = web3.eth.contract(contractAbiGame);
      contractInstanceRegistry.games(i, function(err, res) {
        if (!err) {
          // Create the object
          contractInstanceGame[i] = [];
          contractInstanceGame[i]['Caller'] = contractGame.at(res);
          contractInstanceGame[i]['Address'] = res;

          // Get the Start Time
          contractInstanceGame[i]['Caller'].startTime(function(err, res) {
            if (!err) {
              contractInstanceGame[i]['StartTime'] = res.toNumber();
            } else {
              console.error("Could not get the Game start time: " + err);
            }
          });

          // Get the End Time
          contractInstanceGame[i]['Caller'].endTime(function(err, res) {
            if (!err) {
              contractInstanceGame[i]['EndTime'] = res.toNumber();
            } else {
              console.error("Could not get the Game end time: " + err);
            }
          });  
        } else {
          console.error("Could not get the Game contract address: " + err);
        }
      });
    }

    console.log(contractInstanceGame);
    // Perform the Order of contractInstanceGame by Start Time`
    // Display contractInstanceGame
  } else {
    console.error("Could not get the number of Games: " + err);
  }
```

EDIT:
Examples of the solutions I tried:

Using then() on the call itself does not work as I am facing the following error:
inpage.js:14 Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter. See https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client for details.

```
contractInstanceRegistry.numberOfGames()
.then(function(x){
  console.log(x);
});
```

I also tried to Promisifed and use await, but I am facing the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

```
let numberOfGames = promisify(cb => contractInstanceRegistry.numberOfGames(cb));
let numberOfGamesX = await numberOfGames;
```

Comment: Which function are you referring to? Do you have any error output?

Comment: Which version of web3.js are you using? This sort of thing is easier with promises, which are available in web3.js 1.0.0-beta.

Comment: @smarx I am using v1.0.0-beta.33

Comment: @AdamKipnis I tried different ways, and I am not able to properly wait that all the call of Step 2 are completed (like using  Promisify and Await)

Comment: The error "Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter." indicates that you're _not_ using web3.js 1.0.0-beta.33 but are rather using the injected web3.js from MetaMask, which is version 0.2x.x.

Comment: @smarx Thank you! I was actually using still la 0.X.Y version (from Develop Branch) and not the 1.X.Y-Beta. Once I switch to it I was able to use .then() statement. Feel free to post the answer, I will accept it :)